# Displaying output on multiple lines in arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, netbeans

I have to take marks(numbers) as input from user and then store into array and displaay it. This is what I have got:

```
ArrayList <Integer> marks=new ArrayList();
    private void addActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
marks.add(Integer.parseInt(marksinput.getText()));
Collections.addAll(marks);  
for(int i=0; i < 10;i++){
    marksoutput.setText(marks+"");
}
```

The problem I am having is that it displays output in one line with brackets and commas. I want each mark on new line without brackets and commas. Any help is appreciated and thank you in advance!☻

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
   marksoutput.setText(marks+"\n");
```

`"\n"` will add the new line in between.

Comment: @RamBhatti Ok, try without the `""`

Answer (score 0):

Pretty close. Check out enhanced for-loops. They're great. Also, you could minimize the logic and get rid of `marksoutput`, which is also implemented wrong as your currently overwriting `marksoutput` with each loop iteration because of `setText()`. You need to use `add()` instead, to append each new item to the end of the existing list.

Without `marksoutput` ArrayList example:

```
List <Integer> marks=new ArrayList();

private void addActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                    
    marks.add(Integer.parseInt(marksinput.getText()));

    // Here is the new for-loop, known as an enhanced for-loop
    for(Integer i : marks)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

With `marksoutput` ArrayList example

```
List <Integer> marks=new ArrayList();

private void addActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                    
    marks.add(Integer.parseInt(marksinput.getText()));

    // Here is the new for-loop, known as an enhanced for-loop
    for(Integer i : marks)
    {
        marksout.add(i); // adds the element `i` to the end of `marksout` list
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? Not sure why that would give an error if `marksout` is an `ArrayList<Integer>` or `List<Integer>`, which I assumed it was

Comment: never mind i figured it out. I added a for loop to display the output and it worked

Answer (score 0):

`marks`is an Object of the `ArrayList` that's why you get the input with brackets and commas because when you print the object `marks`, it will print the toString() method of it. you need something like iterating it like this:

```
StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for(Integer num : marks) {
    strBuilder.append(num.toString());
}
marksoutput.setText(strBuilder.toString());
```